# Ember.Select doesn't change selected value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, htmlbars

I've got a select-box with categories inside my post-editor. Ever since using the category permalink as its primary-key the selected value inside the select-field doesn't change anymore visible. However the value is updated correctly in the model.

**What may cause this problem?**

*Everything used to work when permalink was just a property but not the primary key*

**The template**

```
{{view "select"
  content=categories
  selection=model.category
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

**cateogries property in its controller**

```
// categories for select-box
categories: function() {
  return this.get('store').find('category');
}.property(),
```

**The category-model:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post',{async:true})
});
```

**The category serializer:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'permalink'
})
```

Comment: Can you try `optionLabelPath="content.name.content"`?